# Print all defined variables without having line breaks in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a problem here with white space.

So I have the following:

```
$mat1 = empty($just1) ? '' : '- Material 1';
$mat2 = empty($just2) ? '' : '- Material 2';
$mat3 = empty($just3) ? '' : '- Material 3';
$mat4 = empty($just4) ? '' : '- Material 4';
$mat5 = empty($just5) ? '' : '- Material 5';
```

And now getting these in HTML is not how I want. I get white space for empty vars, so if $mat3 is empty, I will get white space. How can I add a quick fix here.

```
<div id="1">'.$mat1.'</div >
<div id="2">'.$mat2.'</div >
<div id="3">'.$mat3.'</div >
<div id="4">'.$mat4.'</div >
<div id="5">'.$mat5.'</div >
```

Comment: Put all the HTML in the variable then just echo the variables... or do a check on each var. I'm also not sure where `$justX`s are coming from but likely it would be easier to use an array.

Comment: @user3783243 $justX is checking if database is true or not

Comment: I think you're asking an XY problem. But a temp solution could be https://3v4l.org/iWJtZ